# Windows not shown in Grub after installing 12.10

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows

I just installed 12.10 alongside Windows 7. I split my partition into two because disk reader during the installation didn't recognize Windows 7 as being installed on the computer. It installed correctly and I restarted only to find out it wasn't recognized in Grub also and booted straight to Ubuntu.

I read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207380/new-12-10-install-windows-not-in-boot-menu) and thought of using **boot-repair** would be fine but I gain this error:

```
gpt detected. 
Please create bios-boot partition (>1MB, unformed filesystem, bios_grub flag). 
This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. 
Then try again.
```

I've no idea what it means or what to do next. Suggestions would be appreciated and I have lost my Windows installation disk and I really don't want to have to go looking for it.

EDIT: This is what boot-repair came back with. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1326230/

Answer (score 0):

Well the error says it all, you have GPT standard so you must also add a BIOS-Boot or an EFI partition depending on the boot mode of your BIOS.

You can read about here..https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: Ok, that fixed the issue with boot-repair not working. I ran the program, however, it still does not detect Windows 7 on the hard drive.

Comment: Well, if you had the windows 7 installation disk it would have been easier I suppose... in that case you had to repair your startup, and if that didn't work, you had to go to cmd via repair and type the following:
1. bootrec /fixBoot
2. bootrec /rebuildBCD
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try going to the terminal via ubuntu and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

And if that too doesn't recognise windows then go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
sudo update-grub
grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If that too doesn't work, see if this might be of any help, 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1007923
It's for 12.04 though.

Let me know if anything worked.

Comment: Those commands didn't really show me or do anything. The link however worked to an extent. I however, just need to find my disk and repair the bootmgr. I don't know how but I'm sure I'll be able to somewhere. Suggestions would be great, we're halfway there.